# Differential equation using $n$th order formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Use the formula for the $n$th roots of a complex number to find the solution to the following differential equation.  $y^{(6)}-64y=0$

$y^{(6)}$ is the $6$th derivative

Comment: i've try to factor it and i tried to turn it into the characteristic equation, both with out luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the ansatz $y(x)=c e^{ax}$. This gives the characteristic equation $a^6=64$ with the six solutions $a_k=2 e^{\frac{2\pi k}{6}}\,$i.e. the doubled $6^{th}$ roots of unity. The general solution is
$$y(x)=\sum_{k=0}^5 c_k e^{a_k x}$$
Since four $a_k$ are complex, you may wish to express these $e^{a_k x}$ with $\exp, \sin, \cos.$

Comment: This was helpful, just one question why isn't it a^6 = 64a?

Comment: For the $n^{th}$ derivative of $y(x)=c e^{ax}$ you have $y^{(n)}(x)=a^n c y(x)=a^n c e^{ax}.$ 
Now  plugin into the differential eqaution and get $(a^6-64)ce^{ax}=0,\,$ with the characteristic equation $a^6-64=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the ansatz $y=e^{\lambda x}$ to get the characteristic polynomial
$$\chi(\lambda)=\lambda^6+64=0.$$

This can be solved by using the fact that $-1=e^{i(\frac{3}{2}\pi+2\pi k)}$ in the equation

$$\lambda^6=-64=2^6\cdot e^{i(\frac{3}{2}\pi+2\pi k)}.$$

Remember that the general solution of this linear ODE with constant coefficients can be expressed as

$$y(x)=c_1e^{\lambda_1 x}+c_2e^{\lambda_2 x}\cdots+c_6e^{\lambda_6 x}.$$

Where $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues of characteristic polynomial.

Can you finish this from here?

Comment: He probably can't, because you didn't include the $64$.